# Failed to bitbake docker in Yocto 4.9.88 (rocko) with meta-virtualization layer

Tags: linux, docker, yocto, lxc

I download meta_virtualization from http://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/branch/master/layer/meta-virtualization/

I bitbake docker, and I have an error as below

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/mnt/Build_Server_Disk3/imx-linux-rocko/ms5776_virtual/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/containerd-docker/v0.2.x+gitAUTOINC+3addd84065-r0/git/src/github.com/containerd/containerd/src/import/vendor/src': No such file or directory
```

I checked the containerd.inc and https://github.com/containerd/containerd/

I found the path "src/import/vendor/src" which doesn't exist in https://github.com/containerd/containerd/

```
do_compile() {
export GOARCH="${TARGET_GOARCH}"

# link fixups for compilation
rm -f ${S}/src/import/vendor/src
ln -sf ./ ${S}/src/import/vendor/src

mkdir -p ${S}/src/import/vendor/src/github.com/containerd/containerd/
mkdir -p ${S}/src/import/vendor/src/github.com/containerd/containerd/pkg/
mkdir -p ${S}/src/import/vendor/src/github.com/containerd/containerd/contrib/
# without this, the stress test parts of the build fail
cp ${S}/src/import/*.go ${S}/src/import/vendor/src/github.com/containerd/containerd

for c in content errdefs fs images mount snapshots linux api runtimes defaults progress \
                 protobuf reference diff platforms runtime remotes version archive dialer gc metadata \
                 metrics filters identifiers labels leases plugin server services \
                 cmd cio containers namespaces oci events log reaper sys rootfs nvidia seed apparmor seccomp; do
    if [ -d ${S}/src/import/${c} ]; then
        ln -sfn ${S}/src/import/${c} ${S}/src/import/vendor/github.com/containerd/containerd/${c}
    fi
    if [ -d ${S}/src/import/pkg/${c} ]; then
        ln -sfn ${S}/src/import/pkg/${c} ${S}/src/import/vendor/github.com/containerd/containerd/pkg/${c}
    fi
    if [ -d ${S}/src/import/contrib/${c} ]; then
        ln -sfn ${S}/src/import/contrib/${c} ${S}/src/import/vendor/github.com/containerd/containerd/contrib/${c}
    fi
done
```

Could anyone tell me how to fix it?

### 20180621

I follow Danior suggestion, it worked, but bitbake docker still failed.
The error log as below

```
ERROR: docker-18.09.3+git667e800b2cf920c6d3d7c32fdbc5811934d99769-r0 do_compile: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /mnt/Build_Server_Disk3/MS5776/20190618/imx-yocto-bsp/imx-linux-rocko/MS5776_V001/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/docker/18.09.3+git667e800b2cf920c6d3d7c32fdbc5811934d99769-r0/temp/log.do_compile.17107)
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /mnt/Build_Server_Disk3/MS5776/20190618/imx-yocto-bsp/imx-linux-rocko/MS5776_V001/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/docker/18.09.3+git667e800b2cf920c6d3d7c32fdbc5811934d99769-r0/temp/log.do_compile.17107
Log data follows:
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_compile
| # WARNING! I don't seem to be running in a Docker container.
| # The result of this command might be an incorrect build, and will not be
| # officially supported.
| #
| # Try this instead: make all
| #
|
| Package devmapper was not found in the pkg-config search path.
| Perhaps you should add the directory containing `devmapper.pc'
| to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
| No package 'devmapper' found
| Removing bundles/
|
| ---> Making bundle: dynbinary (in bundles/dynbinary)
| Building: bundles/dynbinary-daemon/dockerd-18.09.3
| # github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/vbatts/tar-split/archive/tar
| .gopath/src/github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/vbatts/tar-split/archive/tar/writer.go:178:11: undefined: strings.Builder
| # github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/moby/buildkit/util/apicaps
| .gopath/src/github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/moby/buildkit/util/apicaps/caps.go:147:8: undefined: strings.Builder
| # github.com/docker/docker/pkg/archive
| .gopath/src/github.com/docker/docker/pkg/archive/archive.go:365:5: hdr.Format undefined (type *tar.Header has no field or method Format)
| .gopath/src/github.com/docker/docker/pkg/archive/archive.go:365:15: undefined: tar.FormatPAX
| .gopath/src/github.com/docker/docker/pkg/archive/archive.go:1160:7: hdr.Format undefined (type *tar.Header has no field or method Format)
| .gopath/src/github.com/docker/docker/pkg/archive/archive.go:1160:17: undefined: tar.FormatPAX
| .gopath/src/github.com/docker/docker/pkg/archive/copy.go:346:7: hdr.Format undefined (type *tar.Header has no field or method Format)
| .gopath/src/github.com/docker/docker/pkg/archive/copy.go:346:17: undefined: tar.FormatPAX
| # github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/containerd/containerd/archive
| .gopath/src/github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/containerd/containerd/archive/tar.go:409:29: hdr.PAXRecords undefined (type *tar.Header has no field or method PAXRecords)
| .gopath/src/github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/containerd/containerd/archive/tar.go:544:10: hdr.PAXRecords undefined (type *tar.Header has no field or method PAXRecords)
| .gopath/src/github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/containerd/containerd/archive/tar.go:545:8: hdr.PAXRecords undefined (type *tar.Header has no field or method PAXRecords)
| .gopath/src/github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/containerd/containerd/archive/tar.go:547:7: hdr.PAXRecords undefined (type *tar.Header has no field or method PAXRecords)
| # github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/docker/swarmkit/manager/allocator/cnmallocator
| .gopath/src/github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/docker/swarmkit/manager/allocator/cnmallocator/drivers_ipam.go:18:10: undefined: strings.Builder
| WARNING: exit code 2 from a shell command.
| ERROR: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /mnt/Build_Server_Disk3/MS5776/20190618/imx-yocto-bsp/imx-linux-rocko/MS5776_V001/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/docker/18.09.3+git667e800b2cf920c6d3d7c32fdbc5811934d99769-r0/temp/log.do_compile.17107)
ERROR: Task (/mnt/Build_Server_Disk3/MS5776/20190618/imx-yocto-bsp/imx-linux-rocko/sources/meta-virtualization/recipes-containers/docker/docker_git.bb:do_compile) failed with exit code '1'
```

bitbake-layers show-layers

```
NOTE: Starting bitbake server...
layer                 path                                      priority
==========================================================================
meta                  /mnt/Build_Server_Disk3/MS5776/20190617_docker/imx-yocto-bsp/imx-linux-rocko/sources/poky/meta  5
meta-poky             /mnt/Build_Server_Disk3/MS5776/20190617_docker/imx-yocto-bsp/imx-linux-rocko/sources/poky/meta-poky  5
meta-oe               /mnt/Build_Server_Disk3/MS5776/20190617_docker/imx-yocto-bsp/imx-linux-rocko/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-oe  6
meta-multimedia       /mnt/Build_Server_Disk3/MS5776/20190617_docker/imx-yocto-bsp/imx-linux-rocko/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-multimedia  6
meta-freescale        /mnt/Build_Server_Disk3/MS5776/20190617_docker/imx-yocto-bsp/imx-linux-rocko/sources/meta-freescale  5
meta-freescale-3rdparty  /mnt/Build_Server_Disk3/MS5776/20190617_docker/imx-yocto-bsp/imx-linux-rocko/sources/meta-freescale-3rdparty  4
meta-freescale-distro  /mnt/Build_Server_Disk3/MS5776/20190617_docker/imx-yocto-bsp/imx-linux-rocko/sources/meta-freescale-distro  4
meta-bsp              /mnt/Build_Server_Disk3/MS5776/20190617_docker/imx-yocto-bsp/imx-linux-rocko/sources/meta-fsl-bsp-release/imx/meta-bsp  8
meta-sdk              /mnt/Build_Server_Disk3/MS5776/20190617_docker/imx-yocto-bsp/imx-linux-rocko/sources/meta-fsl-bsp-release/imx/meta-sdk  8
meta-browser          /mnt/Build_Server_Disk3/MS5776/20190617_docker/imx-yocto-bsp/imx-linux-rocko/sources/meta-browser  7
meta-gnome            /mnt/Build_Server_Disk3/MS5776/20190617_docker/imx-yocto-bsp/imx-linux-rocko/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-gnome  7
meta-networking       /mnt/Build_Server_Disk3/MS5776/20190617_docker/imx-yocto-bsp/imx-linux-rocko/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-networking  5
meta-python           /mnt/Build_Server_Disk3/MS5776/20190617_docker/imx-yocto-bsp/imx-linux-rocko/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-python  7
meta-filesystems      /mnt/Build_Server_Disk3/MS5776/20190617_docker/imx-yocto-bsp/imx-linux-rocko/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-filesystems  6
meta-qt5              /mnt/Build_Server_Disk3/MS5776/20190617_docker/imx-yocto-bsp/imx-linux-rocko/sources/meta-qt5  7
meta-virtualization   /mnt/Build_Server_Disk3/MS5776/20190617_docker/imx-yocto-bsp/imx-linux-rocko/sources/meta-virtualization  6
meta-ms5776           /mnt/Build_Server_Disk3/MS5776/20190617_docker/imx-yocto-bsp/imx-linux-rocko/sources/meta-ms5776  5
```

bitbake-layers show-overlayed

```
NOTE: Starting bitbake server...
WARNING: Host distribution "ubuntu-18.04" has not been validated with this version of the build system; you may possibly experience unexpected failures. It is recommended that you use a tested distribution.
Loading cache: 100% |##########################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:02
Loaded 3379 entries from dependency cache.
Parsing recipes: 100% |########################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:01
Parsing of 2536 .bb files complete (2534 cached, 2 parsed). 3381 targets, 411 skipped, 8 masked, 0 errors.

Summary: There was 1 WARNING message shown.
=== Overlayed recipes ===
alsa-utils:
  meta-bsp             1.1.5
  meta                 1.1.4
bluez5:
  meta-bsp             5.49
  meta                 5.46
firmware-imx:
  meta-bsp             1:7.5
  meta-freescale       1:5.4
glm:
  meta-bsp             0.9.8.4
  meta-oe              0.9.8.5
imx-alsa-plugins:
  meta-bsp             1.0.26
  meta-freescale       1.0.26
imx-codec:
  meta-bsp             4.3.5
  meta-freescale       4.2.1
imx-gpu-sdk:
  meta-sdk             5.0.2
  meta-freescale-distro 2.3.2
imx-gpu-viv:
  meta-bsp             1:6.2.4.p1.2-aarch32
  meta-bsp             6.2.4.p1.2-aarch64 (skipped)
  meta-freescale       5.0.11.p8.6-hfp (skipped)
imx-gst1.0-plugin:
  meta-bsp             4.3.5
  meta-freescale       4.1.6
imx-kobs:
  meta-bsp             5.5+gitAUTOINC+a0e9adce2f
  meta-freescale       5.5+gitAUTOINC+a2734b9375
imx-lib:
  meta-bsp             1:git
  meta-freescale       1:5.8+AUTOINC+f5f14fc245
imx-parser:
  meta-bsp             4.3.5
  meta-freescale       4.2.1
imx-test:
  meta-bsp             1:7.0+AUTOINC+1f7da41b3a
  meta-freescale       00.00.00
  meta-freescale       1:6.0+AUTOINC+fb250a795c
imx-uuc:
  meta-bsp             0.5.1+gitAUTOINC+323efa5e4c
  meta-freescale       0.5.1+gitAUTOINC+2ae634281a
imx-vpu:
  meta-bsp             1:5.4.38
  meta-freescale       1:5.4.37
imx-vpuwrap:
  meta-bsp             4.3.5
  meta-freescale       1.0.68
kernel-module-imx-gpu-viv:
  meta-bsp             6.2.4.p1.2
  meta-freescale       5.0.11.p8.6+fslc+gitAUTOINC+a05d9b23b9
  meta-freescale       5.0.11.p8.6
libdrm:
  meta-bsp             2.4.84
  meta                 2.4.83
libinput:
  meta-bsp             1.6.1
  meta                 1.8.1
linux-firmware:
  meta-bsp             1:0.0+gitAUTOINC+bf04291309_a0026b646c
  meta                 1:0.0+gitAUTOINC+bf04291309_a0026b646c
linux-imx:
  meta-bsp             4.9.88
  meta-freescale       4.9.11
linux-libc-headers:
  meta-bsp             4.9
  meta                 4.12
opencv:
  meta-bsp             3.4+gitAUTOINC+6d4f66472e_81ca8dab86_a62e20676a_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4
  meta-oe              3.3+gitAUTOINC+87c27a074d_2a9d1b22ed_a62e20676a_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4
oprofile:
  meta-oe              1.1.0
  meta                 1.1.0
python-blinker:
  meta-python          1.4
  meta-virtualization  1.3
python-flask:
  meta-python          0.12.2
  meta-virtualization  0.10.1
python-gevent:
  meta-python          1.2.2
  meta-virtualization  1.0.1
python-m2crypto:
  meta-python          0.26.4
  meta-virtualization  0.22.3
python-pycrypto:
  meta-bsp             2.6.1
  meta-python          2.6.1
python-pyyaml:
  meta-python          3.12
  meta-virtualization  3.11
python-redis:
  meta-python          2.10.6
  meta-virtualization  2.10.3
python-sqlalchemy:
  meta-python          1.1.14
  meta-virtualization  1.0.16
  meta-virtualization  1.1.5
python-werkzeug:
  meta-python          0.12.2
  meta-virtualization  0.10.4
testfloat:
  meta-oe              3a
  meta-freescale       2a (skipped)
u-boot-imx:
  meta-bsp             2017.03
  meta-freescale       2017.03
u-boot-imx-mfgtool:
  meta-bsp             2017.03
  meta-freescale       2017.03
weston:
  meta-bsp             3.0.0
  meta                 2.0.0
xf86-video-fbdev:
  meta-freescale       0.4.2 (skipped)
  meta                 0.4.4 (skipped)
```

Comment: Which is your actual Yocto version? rocko (from the path)? 4.9.88 is not a Yocto version, it is the Linux kernel version.

Comment: Hi Danior, it's rocko.

Comment: Then, it's highly likely that you're running into a version mismatch issue. Have you properly checked out the rocko branch/tag in meta-virtualizartion? The code of the include file you pasted above (containerd.inc) does not correspond to the rocko recipe; you can check the rocko version of the recipe here http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/meta-virtualization/tree/recipes-containers/containerd/containerd.inc?h=rocko. Furthermore, the github repo that holds the sources is https://github.com/docker/containerd/tree/v0.2.x (forked from https://github.com/containerd/containerd/).

Comment: It worked. Now I have another problem :  Package devmapper was not found in  the pkg-config search path, so I bitbake libdevmapper first, and then do  bitbake docker, the problem can't be solved. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Was it about the version mismatch?

Comment: I add libdevmapper in DEPENDS_append_class-target = " lvm2 libdevmapper" in recipes-containers/docker/docker.inc, It worked. but bitbake docker is still failed.

Comment: Hi Danlor, I update the question, you can see the entire log. Is it still a version mismatch or other problems?

Comment: The "build process" for the (non-existent) "target" class is the default; you don't need to specify that. Neither should you modify third-party layers/recipes directly, write a bbappend in your own layer instead.

Comment: It is hard to tell without taking a look over your whole environment. Could you post the result of executing `bitbake-layers show-layers` and `bitbake-layers show-overlayed`?

Comment: Hi danlor, I updated questions

Comment: _"WARNING: Host distribution "ubuntu-18.04" has not been validated with this version of the build system; you may possibly experience unexpected failures. It is recommended that you use a tested distribution."_ This could well be a flaw source.

Comment: BTW, you can perform a `bitbake -c cleanall docker` (or whatever the name of the recipe/package is) and then try to rebuild it from scratch in order to avoid previous builds garbage.

Comment: Hi Danlor, I bitbake docker on Ubuntu 14.04, it's still failed, the error is same as Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Hi Danlor, I git clone https://git.yoctoproject.org/git/meta-virtualization -b rocko, and it works. but the docker version is v17, not v18

Comment: zohanlin: that's fine! Indeed, it is building the right version. So, this confirms my suspections; all this was a version mismatch issue...You can check it here http://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/branch/rocko/recipes/?q=docker (You can use this website to check wheter a recipe is officially supported by a given Yocto version or not, its version and which layer contains it). Should you need a newer version of `docker`, you have to upgrade your Yocto version.

Comment: Hi Danlor, it's very useful. Thanks a lot.